# How to build definition hover capabilities to a new language extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The background is I have a custom JSON based language.

Consider the following

In file 1, I have the following:

```
[
{
   "name" : "abcde",
   "source" : "source::abcde",
   // other attributes
},
{
   "name" : "qwerty",
   "source" : "source::qwerty"
   // other attributes
},
]
```

In file 2, I have the following:

abcde.json

```
{
"name" : "abcde"
// properties related to it
}
```

querty.json

```
{
"name" : "querty"
// properties related to it
}
```

Now, I want to build an extension/ grammar such that when a visitor uses Ctrl + click on source::`abcde`, it takes them to abcde.json.

I am wondering how to achieve through a VS code extension. I dont have a lot of expertise in this area.

I took  a look into https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/ , could not find one directly. I have 10000+ such definitions, it is becoming very hard to maintain and update these.

Any help on how to achieve this? or some pointing blogs would be really helpful

Comment: This is a very big question as it involves several steps with their own problems and solutions. Hence this question does not fit to the Q&A style of Stackoverflow. Check out how to contribute a language implementation to VS Code and continue from there.

Comment: implement a `DocumentLinkProvider` and use `vscode.open` command to open the target file